# Redirect website language mutations to their equivalents on different domain using .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, multilingual

I have a (Joomla) website using domain name `foo.cz`.

This website has language mutations with the following structure:

```
foo.cz/music (the default CZ language has no specific directory)
foo.cz/en/music
foo.cz/fr/music
foo.cz/de/music
foo.cz/es/music
foo.cz/ru/music
```

Now I registered new domain `bar.com` and I want to keep the `.cz` website as it is (for the Czech users), but I need to do the permanent redirect from its language mutations to their equivalents on `bar.com`, so redirects should be:

```
foo.cz/music -> do nothing, no redirect, stay where you are!!!
foo.cz/en/music -> bar.com/en/music
foo.cz/fr/music -> bar.com/fr/music
foo.cz/de/music -> bar.com/de/music
foo.cz/es/music -> bar.com/es/music
foo.cz/ru/music -> bar.com/ru/music
```

**Please note that both domains are pointing to the same location, same document root on the server, so physically, I have still one site, one database, hosted at one exact place.**

I want to do it using `.htaccess` file, in some clever way to avoid some SEO and Google page rank damage. It means that `.cz` default language site content will stay indexed as it is, and other language mutations will be reindexed under new domain `bar.com`.

Both sites are running over `https`.

I was trying something like this in `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?foo\.cz$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://bar.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NE,R=301]
```

... but it didn't work ... I don't want to redirect everything, only the language mutations. So should I specify the language directories in `RewriteCond`?. How? Or is there any better solution? Or am I thinking wrong and this is not simply possible because of the same hosting for both domains? Thanks so much for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to make your pattern match starting language otherwise `^` will redirect everything.

You may use:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?foo\.cz$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^[a-z]{2}/ http://bar.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NE,R=301]
```

`[a-z]{2}/` will match any 2 lowercase letters followed by a `/`.

If you only want to match certain specific languages then this should also work:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?foo\.cz$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(?:en|fr|de|es|ru)/ http://bar.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NE,R=301]
```

Make sure to test this change in a new browser to avoid old cache.

Comment: It works like a charm! I finally used your second example. Thank you very much!